# Scala JavaFx -- Cannot resolve overloaded method 'add' when trying to add tree table columns

Tags: scala

I am trying to write an application using JavaFX and Scala (not ScalaFX). When I tried out this example from http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/treetableview.html (Add TreeTableColumn to TreeTableView), I got a "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'add'" in the last two lines. I was wondering if you can help me get past this issue.

```scala
class Phase1 extends Application {
  import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn
  import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView
  import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory

  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit = {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Experimental Blocking Tree")
    val scene = new Scene(new Group(), 1500, 800)
    val sceneRoot = scene.getRoot.asInstanceOf[Group]

    val treeTableView = new TreeTableView[Car]

    val treeTableColumn1: TreeTableColumn[Car, String] = new TreeTableColumn[Car, String]("Brand")
    val treeTableColumn2: TreeTableColumn[Car, String] = new TreeTableColumn[Car, String]("Model")

    treeTableColumn1.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory[Car, String]("brand"))
    treeTableColumn2.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory[Car, String]("model"))

    treeTableView.getColumns.add(treeTableColumn1)  // cannot resolve overloaded method here
    treeTableView.getColumns.add(treeTableColumn2)  // and here
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code compiles just fine. In IntelliJ, I can see `add` underscored in red with message "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'add'", but that is an issue with IntelliJ not the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with displaying data in `TreeTableView`.
Jarek posted a solution here: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/issues/325#event-3418531621)
Also this works for me:

```
import scalafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty

case class Car (
  val brand: ReadOnlyStringProperty,
  val model: ReadOnlyStringProperty
)

class CarStringFactory(val stringValue: ReadOnlyStringProperty) extends scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[String, String] {
  override def delegate: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[String] = stringValue
  override def value: String = stringValue.get
}


class YourScalaFXApp {

    // ... boilerplate code ...
    import scalafx.scene.control.{TreeTableView, TreeTableColumn}

    val treeTableView = new TreeTableView[Car]

    val treeTableColumn1: TreeTableColumn[Car, String] = new TreeTableColumn[Car, String]("Brand"){
        cellValueFactory = {p => new CarStringFactory(p.value.value.value.brand) }
    }
    val treeTableColumn2: TreeTableColumn[Car, String] = new TreeTableColumn[Car, String]("Model"){
        cellValueFactory = {p => new CarStringFactory(p.value.value.value.model) }
    }

    treeTableView.getColumns.add(treeTableColumn1)
    treeTableView.getColumns.add(treeTableColumn2)
}
```

Refer to

- ScalaFX documentation: [Properties](http://www.scalafx.org/docs/properties/)
- [TreeTableColumn.cellValueFactory](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/blob/master/scalafx/src/main/scala/scalafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.scala#L286-L309)